# GoCardless API access with self signed certificate

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl, gocardless

I have a Laravel project in which I'm using the GoCardless API with the PHP Client wrapper from https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-pro-php. I have set it up very simply like so.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use GoCardlessPro\Client;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the index page where we begin a payment flow.
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the GoCardLess Client.
        $client = new Client([
            'access_token' => config('gocardless.token'),
            'environment' => config('gocardless.environment')
        ]);

        $customers = $client->customers()->list();

        dd($customers);
    }
}
```

However, whenever I attempt to make an API call I get the following error.

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired (see
> https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for
> https://api-sandbox.gocardless.com/customers

I am using Laragon on my local machine, and one thing two things that provides are:

1. Pretty URLs using Virtual Hosts
2. SSL certificates for your URLs

I feel the issue lies in the fact that the Laragon SSL certificate is self signed.

Here is the folder with the related items.

[image]

I found a related issue on GitHub -> https://github.com/gocardless/gocardless-pro-php/issues/126

However, I spoke to a GoCardless developer and they said the following:

> For the SSL issue this is most likely an issue on your localhost or
> Laravel - It's possible that if you still have the expired root CA
> cert in your trust store then OpenSSL is building a path to the bad CA
> cert and therefore considering it expired when it shouldn't be. See
> this post for details:
> https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/
> Our team ran into this issue on some of our machines which were
> running OpenSSL 1.0.2, as an example I use Mamp to run my PHP, after
> updating Mamp and homebrew it subsequently updated openssl

Comment: What makes you think this had anything to do with your own certificates? The error message says _"... for `https://api-sandbox.gocardless.com/customers`"_

Comment: I'll amend my question, as this is a fair point.

Comment: @CBroe the project also works on my development server, where the only difference is that the SSL certificate isn't self signed.

Comment: This isn't about what self-signed certificate you might use to access your site, but about the expired root certificate for Let's Encrypt certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the Laragon discussion form and was pointed in the direction of this link: https://forum.laragon.org/topic/1472/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/2

Essentially I just updated my `cacert.pem` with the link provided. The file in question is located here `C:\laragon\etc\ssl\cacert.pem`.

If anything, the difference I saw was the addition of the following:

```
ISRG Root X1
============
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFazCCA1OgAwIBAgIRAIIQz7DSQONZRGPgu2OCiwAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwTzELMAkGA1UE
BhMCVVMxKTAnBgNVBAoTIEludGVybmV0IFNlY3VyaXR5IFJlc2VhcmNoIEdyb3VwMRUwEwYDVQQD
EwxJU1JHIFJvb3QgWDEwHhcNMTUwNjA0MTEwNDM4WhcNMzUwNjA0MTEwNDM4WjBPMQswCQYDVQQG
EwJVUzEpMCcGA1UEChMgSW50ZXJuZXQgU2VjdXJpdHkgUmVzZWFyY2ggR3JvdXAxFTATBgNVBAMT
DElTUkcgUm9vdCBYMTCCAiIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggIPADCCAgoCggIBAK3oJHP0FDfzm54r
Vygch77ct984kIxuPOZXoHj3dcKi/vVqbvYATyjb3miGbESTtrFj/RQSa78f0uoxmyF+0TM8ukj1
3Xnfs7j/EvEhmkvBioZxaUpmZmyPfjxwv60pIgbz5MDmgK7iS4+3mX6UA5/TR5d8mUgjU+g4rk8K
b4Mu0UlXjIB0ttov0DiNewNwIRt18jA8+o+u3dpjq+sWT8KOEUt+zwvo/7V3LvSye0rgTBIlDHCN
Aymg4VMk7BPZ7hm/ELNKjD+Jo2FR3qyHB5T0Y3HsLuJvW5iB4YlcNHlsdu87kGJ55tukmi8mxdAQ
4Q7e2RCOFvu396j3x+UCB5iPNgiV5+I3lg02dZ77DnKxHZu8A/lJBdiB3QW0KtZB6awBdpUKD9jf
1b0SHzUvKBds0pjBqAlkd25HN7rOrFleaJ1/ctaJxQZBKT5ZPt0m9STJEadao0xAH0ahmbWnOlFu
hjuefXKnEgV4We0+UXgVCwOPjdAvBbI+e0ocS3MFEvzG6uBQE3xDk3SzynTnjh8BCNAw1FtxNrQH
usEwMFxIt4I7mKZ9YIqioymCzLq9gwQbooMDQaHWBfEbwrbwqHyGO0aoSCqI3Haadr8faqU9GY/r
OPNk3sgrDQoo//fb4hVC1CLQJ13hef4Y53CIrU7m2Ys6xt0nUW7/vGT1M0NPAgMBAAGjQjBAMA4G
A1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNVHRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBR5tFnme7bl5AFzgAiIyBpY
9umbbjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAVR9YqbyyqFDQDLHYGmkgJykIrGF1XIpu+ILlaS/V9lZL
ubhzEFnTIZd+50xx+7LSYK05qAvqFyFWhfFQDlnrzuBZ6brJFe+GnY+EgPbk6ZGQ3BebYhtF8GaV
0nxvwuo77x/Py9auJ/GpsMiu/X1+mvoiBOv/2X/qkSsisRcOj/KKNFtY2PwByVS5uCbMiogziUwt
hDyC3+6WVwW6LLv3xLfHTjuCvjHIInNzktHCgKQ5ORAzI4JMPJ+GslWYHb4phowim57iaztXOoJw
TdwJx4nLCgdNbOhdjsnvzqvHu7UrTkXWStAmzOVyyghqpZXjFaH3pO3JLF+l+/+sKAIuvtd7u+Nx
e5AW0wdeRlN8NwdCjNPElpzVmbUq4JUagEiuTDkHzsxHpFKVK7q4+63SM1N95R1NbdWhscdCb+ZA
JzVcoyi3B43njTOQ5yOf+1CceWxG1bQVs5ZufpsMljq4Ui0/1lvh+wjChP4kqKOJ2qxq4RgqsahD
YVvTH9w7jXbyLeiNdd8XM2w9U/t7y0Ff/9yi0GE44Za4rF2LN9d11TPAmRGunUHBcnWEvgJBQl9n
JEiU0Zsnvgc/ubhPgXRR4Xq37Z0j4r7g1SgEEzwxA57demyPxgcYxn/eR44/KJ4EBs+lVDR3veyJ
m+kXQ99b21/+jh5Xos1AnX5iItreGCc=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```